# 4 element super conductor without oxygen and iron

Tags: nuclear-physics, superconductivity, spectroscopy, material-science

I am trying to find a list with super conductors. In particular I am searching for a superconductor, that consists of 4 elements none of which is Oxygen.

The reason I rejected Oxygen, is because(from the kinematic factor) the maximum energy from scattering with the Oxygen is about $730 keV$.

Therefore-unfortunately-I have to reject *YBCO* superconductors.

In particular I have to analyse an [RBS spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_backscattering_spectrometry) of a supposed 4-element well known super conductor.

I can't find any 4-element-superconductor without oxygen. Is there anyone, or it might be the case where the sample is bad described?

Just for reference the RBS spectrum is

[image]

**EDIT**

I also tested iron based superconductors, but it seems that I need a heavier element. For instance a superconductor containing $Ba, K, Fe, As$ has the following RBS spectrum

[image]

Please ignore the concentrations...

The analysis indicates that the superconductors consists of 4 elements which are

- Bi(28.5%)
- Sr(28.4%)
- Cu(28.2%)
- K(14.8%)

Does a superconductor like that really exists? I mean OK about Bismuth or Copper or even Strontium...How about Potassium? The combination of those doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: A very cursory search found Ba$_{0.6}$K$_{0.4}$Fe$_2$As$_2$. I guess looking at the Pnictides in general could be good bet

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Thank you very much for your comment! I've used your superconductor, but it appears that iron-based are not suitable... It must be a heavier element...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron-based_superconductor) you have a list of non-oxygen containing 4-element pnictides. It might not be a thorough list, but it might help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It appears though, that it cannot be iron based;it has to be heavier than iron... Please see my edited question!